# javascript replace img src with full img url

Tags: javascript, php, html, image

ok so I have a JSON feed which for some reason gives some images like

```
img src=\"..\/..\/upload\/Politcis\/Tony-Abbott.jpg\" alt=\"Tony-Abbott.jpg\" width=\"980\" height=\"653\" align=\"left\" \/>
```

full JSON string `http://media.queerdio.com/mobileDevice/?uri=loadstory/high-court-to-decide-on-act-marriage-law`

What I would like to know if how can I with javascript replace the img src with the full img src.

for this image according to there API the full img src should be.

```
http://media.queerdio.com/news/upload/Politcis/Tony-Abbott.jpg
```

what I know if I would have to first get the src link, and split it at the beginning of upload

then I would need a var linking to `http://media.queerdio.com/news/`
then I would add the upload and the rest of the src link to it, then replace the img src.

so I understand the basics of what I want to do but note 100% sure how to do what i need.

Comment: any library using?? with jQuery???

Comment: I'm confused about what you're asking. Getting the JSON from that url the `featured_image` attribute appears to be what you need : `http:\/\/queerdio.com\/upload\/Politcis\/Tony-Abbott.jpg`

Comment: is there any javascript library included at your website, such as jQuery / dojo / ExtJS, or any others??

Comment: no jquery sorry guys,

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pseudo code in case your site already has jQuery:

```
var htmlFromJson; //you json object
var imgHost = 'http://media.queerdio.com/news/';
$(htmlFromJson).find('img').each( //find the img from the JSON str
    function(){
        var newSrc = imgHost + $(this).attr('src'); //access add custom host in img src
        newSrc = fixUrl(newSrc); //remember to replace the ../ & parent folder name
        $(this).attr('src', newSrc); // update the 
    }
);
```

Hope I can help you. PS: if you somewhere mis-understand, let me know, I try to solve.

Comment: no i think you have it correct by I dont use jquery or any framework